# Typicon local directory location

Tags: css, html, fonts, icons

i downloaded a source code for a navigation in web, and in the source code there is this "Typicon"

in the HTML he include this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
```

.

```
<a href="#" class="icon-home">Home</a>
```

in the component CSS here is this.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'typicons';
    src:url('../fonts/typicons/typicons.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/typicons/typicons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/typicons/typicons.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/typicons/typicons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/typicons/typicons.svg#typicons') format('svg');
```

.

```
.icon-home::before { content: "\e601" }
```

I want to change the logo of certain class but I cant seem to find the directory for all the icons in the folder in which I can choose from.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not the directory where the icons are located. They're on the font files. What you need is the HEX code of the icons you want to use in your classes.

One way (free, by the way) is to upload the .ttf file to either [Flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com/font-face) or [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), so that you can create a CSS file with all the hex codes.

Note that this can also be used to create Webfonts from any FREE font and that the CSS file adds CSS classes for each glyph/icon (so that you can use the CSS class instead of remembering/fetching the icons' codes).

Comment: Is there such way, where I can view the design and the HEX code without internet?

Comment: Once you create and donwload the font kit, you can view the codes by opening the CSS file that comes with it, so that you don't need internet access once you downloaded it. Alternatively, you can use a FontViewer or Character Mapper, such as http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Font-Utils/dp4-Font-Viewer.shtml where you can view/copy the codes.